# How does review suspension work on Meta?

Tags: support, meta, review-suspension

I made a noob review mistake a few days ago, so I'm suspended from review until Aug 16.

However, I can see Suggested Edits review queue in Meta (although the review queue is already cleared as always).

Is it because

- Review suspension in the main site is not applied to the meta site, or
- [Recently improved experience for review suspension](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351118/improved-experience-for-users-with-review-suspensions) still has not been deployed to Meta?

And, is there review suspension on Meta?

Comment: Very related, maybe even a dupe: [Can we be banned from meta reviews? If yes, will I be banned from reviews on the main site?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307852)

Comment: @Tom Thanks for the link. It's so hard to search meta questions. I searched "review suspension in meta stackoverflow" but that does not show anything both in Google and MSO.

Comment: @bravemaster yeah don't use so many words in the site search :) Search as if you're a cave man. "Review suspension meta, unga bunga".

Comment: @Gimby Searching by "Review suspension meta [unga bunga]" will only show posts of users complaining their review suspension in SO. :D